# Using svg from the same document as separate menu items

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to customize the icons used in coddyhouse's [secondary fixed navigation](https://codyhouse.co/gem/secondary-fixed-navigation/).
When trying to open the svg file in AI there are all the icons in a row ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0nti.jpg) part 1), so I tried to just replace the icons with the ones I want (resizing the icons i want and putting them exactly on the original ones), but this results in all the icons showing as a single item's background (as if what divided them to separate icons isn't active anymore), this can be seen in part 4 of the screenshot.
Trying to look at the original svg code (I put representing part of it in part 3) and css (part 2) I couldn't find anything helpful, nor in the html, where the menu items look like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#cd-placeholder-1">
        <b>about</b>
        <span></span><!-- icon -->
    </a>
</li>
```

I hope there is enough information now. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: How come you have a closing `</p>` after closing `</li>` element? Shouldn't you wrap it with `<ul></ul>` / `<ol></ol>`?

Comment: oops... that's just me learning how to format my code in stackoverflow :) I wanted to make the code show as separate paragraph and the closing tag "slipped away" :) and there is a wrapping ul around the whole menu, I just wanted to show how a menu item looks

Comment: That is an issue of background size ... if you did not change anything in the CSS, then most likely your edited SVG differs from the original in that regard (could be due to viewbox or width/height attributes in the SVG, or sth. like that.)